# ExecutePostProcessingAsync throws 'Index was out of range' during Azure Upload

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Trying to upload a file from a form to Azure Blob storage.  The code seems to work and the file does upload correctly.  I just can't figure out why it's throwing this exception.

Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.\r\nParameter name: index"}

```
public override Stream GetStream(HttpContent parent, HttpContentHeaders headers)
{
    if (parent == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("parent");
    }
    if (headers == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("headers");
    }

            var fileName = this.GetLocalFileName(headers);

            //BlobName = BlobName + fileName;

            CloudBlockBlob blob = this.BlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
            blob.Metadata["Created"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();

            if (headers.ContentType != null)
            {
                blob.Properties.ContentType = headers.ContentType.MediaType;
            }

            this.FileData.Add(new MultipartFileData(headers, blob.Name));
            return blob.OpenWrite();

}
```

The exception happens here:

```
public override Task ExecutePostProcessingAsync()
        {

            return base.ExecutePostProcessingAsync();
        }
```

Code inside my ApiController:

```
var provider = new AzureBlobMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(container, blobPath);
                await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same issue.